# Unable to create user object in rails backend using JWT authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, authentication, jwt

I am trying to create User objects in a rails PostgreSQL database using JWT authentication. When I fire the create user method from my React frontend the user is not created in the backend and I suspect this has something to do with how my controllers are set up.

Here is my User controller in my Rails backend:

```rb
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_user, only: [:show]
  skip_before_action :authorized, only: [:index, :create]

  def index
    @users = User.all
    render json: @users
  end

  def show
    render json: @user
  end

  def create
    @user = User.create(user_params)
    if @user.valid?
      @token = encode_token(user_id: @user.id)
      render json: { user: UserSerializer.new(@user), jwt: @token }, status: :created
    else
      render json: {error: "Could not create user"}, status: :unprocessible_entity
    end
  end

end

private

def user_params
  params.permit(:username, :password)
end

def find_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Here is my 'auth' controller for JWT:

```rb
class Api::V1::AuthController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authorized, only: [:create]

  def create # POST /api/v1/login
    @user = User.find_by(username: user_login_params[:username])
    if @user && @user.authenticate(user_login_params[:password])
      @token = encode_token({ user_id: @user.id })
      render json: { user: UserSerializer.new(@user), jwt: @token }, status: :accepted
    else
      render json: { message: 'Invalid username or password' }, status: :unauthorized
    end
  end

  private

  def user_login_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password)
  end
end
```

And my application controller (I suspect the issue is here and has to do with the way in which I am encoding and decoding the tokens):

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  before_action :authorized

  def encode_token(payload) 
    JWT.encode(payload, ENV["jwt_secret"]) 
  end

  def auth_header
    request.headers['Authorization']
  end

  def decoded_token
    if auth_header()
      token = auth_header.split(' ')[1] 
      begin
        JWT.decode(token, ENV["jwt_secret"], true, algorithm: 'HS256')
      rescue JWT::DecodeError
        nil
      end
    end
  end

  def current_user
    if decoded_token()
      user_id = decoded_token[0]['user_id'] 
      @user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def logged_in?
    !!current_user
  end

  def authorized
    render json: { message: 'Please log in' }, status: :unauthorized unless logged_in?
  end
end
```

From my front-end I am using a fetch method to POST to the /users/ endpoint like so:

```js
export const signupUser = (username, password) => {
  return(dispatch) => {
    const data = {user: {username, password} }
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users',{
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(r=>r.json())
    .then(r=>{
      localStorage.setItem('jwt', r.jwt)
      dispatch({
        type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
        payload: r.user
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Apologies that this is long-winded. I wanted to include all the code necessary to figure this out. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you are not saving your user object when you using a function to create user. Please check `app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb` and modify following with `valid` to `save` method

```
def create
    @user = User.create(user_params)
    if @user.valid?
      @token = encode_token(user_id: @user.id)
      render json: { user: UserSerializer.new(@user), jwt: @token }, status: :created
    else
      render json: {error: "Could not create user"}, status: :unprocessible_entity
    end
  end
```

Change the line `@user.valid?` to `@user.save`

```
def create
    @user = User.create(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @token = encode_token(user_id: @user.id)
      render json: { user: UserSerializer.new(@user), jwt: @token }, status: :created
    else
      render json: {error: "Could not create user"}, status: :unprocessible_entity
    end
  end
```

Please note .valid? is used to validate and check if any error, and .save is used to save it. You are just checking validation and not actually saving, validation happen automatically so there is no need for this method here.